# My unit checking variable isn't reading the input properly, when I put cm in as input the program sends the boolean to the else

Tags: python, boolean, python-3.3, boolean-logic

when I enter cm into the uCheck variable the program prints the string in the else condition

```
uCheck=input(print('Unit?')) #<--I enter 'cm' here
if uCheck=='nm':
    Wave=Wave
if uCheck=='cm': #<--it seems to skip this boolean
    Wave=Wave*(10**7)
if uCheck=='mm':
    Wave=Wave*(10**6)
if uCheck=='m':
    Wave=Wave*(10**9)
else:
    print('Invalid Unit! Valid units are: nm, mm, cm, m.') #<-- and prints this
    Frequency()
```

Comment: you can get rid of `print` -- `input('Unit?')` should work just fine ... [reference](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: Whatever happened to the micro metre?  I know mu isn't on most keyboards but um is often accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements are separate. Even if the first one is true, you'll still check the second one, and the third one, and the fourth one, and since only the first one was true, the `else` block will be executed.

Change them to `elif` and your code should work:

```
uCheck = input('Unit? ')

if uCheck == 'nm':
    Wave = Wave
elif uCheck == 'cm':
    ...
```

Also, a better way to do this would be with a dictionary:

```
units = {
    'nm': 1,
    'mm': 10**6,
    'cm': 10**7,
    'm': 10**9
}

unit = input('Unit? ')

if unit in units:
    wave *= units[unit]
else:
    print('Invalid Unit! Valid units are: ' + ', '.join(units))
    frequency()
```